# Compare two views in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I am looking for a way to compare two views in salesforce.  I want to create a visual force page that lets a user select two views associated with the Account object and show all the accounts that appear on both views.

I am struggling pretty hard here, I can't figure out how to get the results from the views, but I am hoping there is a way to get all accounts that match the filters for each view.

Here is my SOQL query:

```
 Select Id, Name, Owner.Name  FROM Account WHERE
    Id IN ( SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE RecordTypeId = :RecordType1ID  AND StageName IN :StageOneList )
    AND Id IN ( SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE RecordTypeId = :RecordType2ID AND StageName IN :StageTwoList )
```

This is the basis of the VF page I have made so far.  It is possible to filter the Account with Account Owner and a drop down list from province.  The idea is, many people in the organization have already created views with the accounts filtered as they need it.  Instead of including every possible account field as a filter, I would like a drop down list of the active users views associated with Account, and then they can select Opportunity 1 and Opportunity 2 and have a list of Accounts matching.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean views as in the available views in the dropdown box on a standard tab for an object? If so I don't believe you can query the results from them directly although you can query the Account object using a SOQL statement where you provide the filter.

My suggestion would be either create a set VF page that has 2 drop downs to switch the SOQL query that is used to return the list of accounts being displayed (would mean you have a set of predetermined views and updates to them require code updates) or give more details of your use case and we may be able to provide other suggestions.

Comment: I would like to find something that can use the views that users make, so this VF page will appear to be quite customizable, but your preset code idea will be my backup if I can't the full functionality that I want.  I will update my question with my SOQL query.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to compare the results of the filters here. My suggestion would be that you're really trying to do something that should be done with reports, not with views.

Comment: Its something we have been trying to do with reports, but the functionality just isn't there.  Our final product/report should show Accounts that show two specific Opportunities, at two specific Stages, filtered by other attributes (such as Account location, owner, and other broad and totally random filters).  Now, it was super easy to work with in the standard report behaviour to make a view of each of the opportunities individually, and now the challenge is to merge those two lists and get the Accounts that appear on both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Put two [enhancedList](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_compref_enhancedList.htm#kanchor902) components on the page.